# Alterar text do label enquanto roda um laço no server

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net, vb.net

Tenho uma tela que faz um processamento demorado, e lá tem um *for* que a cada *next*, quero setar uma label para o usuário ir vendo o processo.

Sei que pode ser feito por ajax, mas não encontrei nada como exemplo.
Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Você poderia usar uma barra de progresso e exibir a %, serve ?

Comment: É WebForms ou MVC? C# ou VB?

Comment: é vb, web. Mas podem enviar sugestões c# que eu converto...

Comment: Olá, Tenta usar isso aqui. http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/RealTime_Progress_Bar_With_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx

Comment: irei dar uma lida Paulo, depois volta a comentar se deu certo.

Comment: Paulo, eu baixei o projeto, executei mas não funciona... ele fica estático e não dinâmico como eu gostaria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sei que não foi a melhor solução, mas eu precisava ser rápido e como já havia revirado o google e nada ajudou resolvi fazer dessa forma.

Na tela que faz o processamento, onde tem o laço, no click do botão, eu chamo uma function javascript que abre um popup e o onclick do server continua o mesmo. No laço eu seto o status na *application*, em quantas % e mais algumas informações. No novo popup eu tenho um Timer que requisita (*OnTick*) a cada 10 segundos. No método que ele requisita, eu recupero o status da *application* e seto em labels na tela.

Ou seja, a cada 10 segundos vai atualizando para o usuário como está o processamento.